# cardano node sync stop at 99%

Tags: cardano-node

i am trying to setup cardano test node but i am getting this error in console and it stuck on 99%

````
[185:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Notice:610213] [2022-07-10 15:16:41.88 UTC] Domain: "relays-new.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io" Connection Attempt Start, destination 13.41.9.54:3001
[185:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Notice:610214] [2022-07-10 15:16:41.90 UTC] Domain: "relays-new.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io" Connection Attempt Start, destination 3.131.32.242:3001
[185:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Notice:610213] [2022-07-10 15:16:41.93 UTC] Domain: "relays-new.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io" Connection Attempt End, destination 13.41.9.54:3001 outcome: ConnectSuccess
[185:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Notice:610215] [2022-07-10 15:16:41.93 UTC] Domain: "relays-new.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io" Connection Attempt Start, destination 54.199.108.71:3001
[185:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Notice:610216] [2022-07-10 15:16:41.96 UTC] Domain: "relays-new.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io" Connection Attempt Start, destination 3.133.220.20:3001
[185:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Notice:610230] [2022-07-10 15:16:41.98 UTC] Domain: "relays-new.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io" Connection Attempt Start, destination 18.198.216.177:3001
[185:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Notice:610231] [2022-07-10 15:16:42.01 UTC] Domain: "relays-new.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io" Connection Attempt Start, destination 184.169.196.177:3001
[185:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Notice:610230] [2022-07-10 15:16:42.02 UTC] Domain: "relays-new.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io" Connection Attempt End, destination 18.198.216.177:3001 outcome: ConnectSuccessLast
[185:cardano.node.ErrorPolicy:Notice:51] [2022-07-10 15:16:42.02 UTC] IP 3.131.32.242:3001 ErrorPolicySuspendConsumer (Just (ConnectionExceptionTrace (SubscriberError {seType = SubscriberParallelConnectionCancelled, seMessage = "Parallel connection cancelled", seStack = []}))) 1s
[185:cardano.node.ErrorPolicy:Notice:51] [2022-07-10 15:16:42.02 UTC] IP 54.199.108.71:3001 ErrorPolicySuspendConsumer (Just (ConnectionExceptionTrace (SubscriberError {seType = SubscriberParallelConnectionCancelled, seMessage = "Parallel connection cancelled", seStack = []}))) 1s
[185:cardano.node.ErrorPolicy:Notice:51] [2022-07-10 15:16:42.02 UTC] IP 3.133.220.20:3001 ErrorPolicySuspendConsumer (Just (ConnectionExceptionTrace (SubscriberError {seType = SubscriberParallelConnectionCancelled, seMessage = "Parallel connection cancelled", seStack = []}))) 1s
[185:cardano.node.ErrorPolicy:Notice:51] [2022-07-10 15:16:42.02 UTC] IP 184.169.196.177:3001 ErrorPolicySuspendConsumer (Just (ConnectionExceptionTrace (SubscriberError {seType = SubscriberParallelConnectionCancelled, seMessage = "Parallel connection cancelled", seStack = []}))) 1s
[185:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Error:610213] [2022-07-10 15:16:42.22 UTC] Domain: "relays-new.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io" Application Exception: 13.41.9.54:3001 MuxError (MuxIOException Network.Socket.recvBuf: resource vanished (Connection reset by peer)) "(recv errored)"
[185:cardano.node.ErrorPolicy:Warning:51] [2022-07-10 15:16:42.22 UTC] IP 13.41.9.54:3001 ErrorPolicySuspendPeer (Just (ApplicationExceptionTrace (MuxError (MuxIOException Network.Socket.recvBuf: resource vanished (Connection reset by peer)) "(recv errored)"))) 20s 20s
[185:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Error:610230] [2022-07-10 15:16:42.31 UTC] Domain: "relays-new.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io" Application Exception: 18.198.216.177:3001 MuxError (MuxIOException Network.Socket.recvBuf: resource vanished (Connection reset by peer)) "(recv errored)"
[185:cardano.node.ErrorPolicy:Warning:51] [2022-07-10 15:16:42.31 UTC] IP 18.198.216.177:3001 ErrorPolicySuspendPeer (Just (ApplicationExceptionTrace (MuxError (MuxIOException Network.Socket.recvBuf: resource vanished (Connection reset by peer)) "(recv errored)"))) 20s 20s```
````

Comment: i have updated cardano-node to 1.35.3 still same issue issue i am facing, syncing stoped

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade to node 1.35.0 (better to use 1.35.1) to sync post Vasil HF

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have the latest genesis and config files for your node version. Hi have seen this symptoms in the past with nodes that had not updated files, so you may check for it. Depending on how you are managing the node your update procedure may be different, but in general you can find the latest versions in the official repository:

https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/tree/master/configuration/cardano

Also, check that you are not out of disk:

```
df -h
```

and the logs for any meaningful hint:

```
journalctl -f -e
```

Cheers,
Josep

Comment: Just checking as Im having the same issue, but according to that link, yes the config files have been updated but the genesis files are all over 2 years old... some even older. Is this correct?

Comment: Hi Bertus, yes they are that old. You can check they are not corrupted checking their hash, i.e. from your files directory, cardano-cli byron genesis print-genesis-hash --genesis-json byron-genesis.json should output 5f20df933584822601f9e3f8c024eb5eb252fe8cefb24d1317dc3d432e940ebb , cardano-cli genesis hash --genesis shelley-genesis.json should output 
1a3be38bcbb7911969283716ad7aa550250226b76a61fc51cc9a9a35d9276d81, and cardano-cli genesis hash --genesis alonzo-genesis.json should output 
7e94a15f55d1e82d10f09203fa1d40f8eede58fd8066542cf6566008068ed874. How many time have been stuck at 99%?